# jQuery How do set text in a input field then press enter?

Tags: jquery, selenium, input, set, enter

jQuery How do set text in a input field then press enter?  I have input field if I manually enter text then submit button will get enabled but if I use jQuery to enter text, then the button won't enabled. How can I make the button enabled?  I am using jQuery with Selenium

Here is what I am looking for verizonwireless.com/support/contact-us on this page, if you enter something in search field, "X" will show up but if you enter using JQuery it won't. So how will I make the "X" show up when I use jquery to enter the text? $('#vgn_q').val('iphone').change(); I tried this but no luck

Comment: Share what you have tried so far.. the relevant HTML and JS

Comment: fire the change event.... If you showed your code, probably have an answer by now. But why are you not using Selenium to alter the form values?

Comment: $('#phone').val('123-123-1234')  This will set the value to the edit box.  When I enter the value manually submit button will enabled because you are typing.  If I use Jquery I am not actually typing so submit button will not be enabled.  how will I perform a change or typing scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

Change button condition when have some value in input

```
var input = $("input");
var target = $("button");

input.on("change keyup",function(){
        if($(this).val() !== ''){
    target.prop("disabled",false);
  }else{
    target.prop("disabled",true);
  }
})
```

jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/synz/uxk87xjb/

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution

```js
$("input").on("change keyup",function(){
  if($(this).val() !== ''){
    $('button').prop("disabled",false);
  }else{
    $('button').prop("disabled",true);
  }
})


//Setting the value using jQuery
setTimeout(function(){
  $('input').val("test").change();
}, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
<button disabled="disabled">submit</button>
```

I've used setTimeout to showcase the value of the input textbox is set after 2secs.

After setting the value of input textbox you need to trigger the change event.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Check length after set value on text box and enable disable your button.

```js
$('#phone').val('123-123-1234')
if ($('#phone').val().length > 0)
  $('#btnSubmit').removeAttr('disabled');
else
  $('#btnSubmit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
$('#phone').keyup(function() {
  if ($(this).val() != '') {
    $('#btnSubmit').removeAttr('disabled');
  } else {
    $('#btnSubmit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='phone' type='text'/>
<input type='button' disabled='disabled' id='btnSubmit' value='Submit' />
```

Comment: I didn't find a solution but work around is set the input box then remove the disabled attribute from button as Shree mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to do it with following code.

```
var e = jQuery.Event( "keypress" );
$('#vgn_q').val('iPhone').trigger(e);
```